# Problems with web scraping (William Hill-UFC Odds)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm creating a web scraper that will let me get the odds of upcoming UFC Fights on William Hill. I'm using beautiful soup but have yet been able to successfully scrape the needed data. (https://sports.williamhill.com/betting/en-gb/ufc)

I need the fighters names and their odds.

I've attempted a variety of methods to try get the data, trying to scrape different tags etc., but nothing happens.

```
def scrape_data():
    data = requests.get("https://sports.williamhill.com/betting/en- 
gb/ufc")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')
    links = soup.find_all('a',{'class': 'btmarket__name btmarket__name-- 
featured'}, href=True)

        for link in links:

        links.append(link.get('href'))

        for link in links:
        print(f"Now currently scraping link: {link}")

        data = requests.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')
        time.sleep(1)            

        fighters = soup.find_all('p', {'class': "btmarket__name"})
        c = fighters[0].text.strip()
        d = fighters[1].text.strip()

        f1.append(c)
        f2.append(d)

        odds = soup.find_all('span', {'class': "betbutton_odds"})

        a = odds[0].text.strip()
        b = odds[1].text.strip()

        f1_odds.append(a)
        f2_odds.append(b)

    return None
```

I would expect it to be exported to a CSV file. I'm currently using `Morph.io` to host and run the scraper, but it returns nothing.

If correct, it would output:

1. Fighter1Name:
2. Fighter2Name:
3. F1Odds:
4. F2Odds:

For every available fight.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the url loads content dynamically meaning making call to API and refresh the page with content. Using plain http request will not give you the content. You need to use any of the headless browsers.

Comment: Have you tried adding some `print()` statements along the way to see the data it's getting?

Answer (score 0):

The html returned has different attributes and values. You need to inspect the response.

For writing out to csv you will want to append "'" in front of odds to prevent odds being treated as fractions or dates. See commented out alternatives in code below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://sports.williamhill.com/betting/en-gb/ufc')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
results = []

for item in soup.select('.btmarket:has([data-odds])'):
    match_name = item.select_one('.btmarket__name[title]')['title']
    odds = [i['data-odds'] for i in item.select('[data-odds]')]
    row = {'event-starttime' : item.select_one('[datetime]')['datetime']        
     ,'match_name' : match_name 
     ,'home_name' : match_name.split(' vs ')[0]
     #,'home_odds' : "'" + str(odds[0])
     ,'home_odds' : odds[0]
     ,'away_name' : match_name.split(' vs ')[1]
     ,'away_odds' :  odds[1]
     #,'away_odds' : "'" + str(odds[1])
   }
    results.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = ['event-starttime','match_name','home_name','home_odds','away_name','away_odds'])
print(df.head())
#write to csv
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```

Comment: Did you try this?